# VBA Code that will iterate through each Row, and then copy/paste data from the origin sheet to the correct cell in the destination sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I can achieve this task by these code chunks:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQMVo.png)

The problem I have is that the total number of rows can vary, and I do not want to have to go back and add more chunks of code for each additional product whenever that happens.

Is there a way I can loop through every row in the worksheet, and then have the data copy and paste to the correct destination cell like I currently have in the code above?

Comment: sure you can make two loops around that ... one for the columns in use and one for the rows/products in use. How many products are available can be determined in VBA as well. So overall this could be converted to a fully automated procedure on the end of the day. Have a look into the .Cells(i, j) type of cell referencing instead of R1C1 writing for that

Comment: Paste your code as code next time, not a screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure how your worksheets look like, but you can find lastrow by:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).row
```

This will give you last row in column U. For me, based on your code, seems like you need to find last column

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyCopyPasteScript()
    
    Dim i
    
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet: Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NANF Formatted")
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NANF")

    Dim lastColumn As Long
    lastColumn = wsSource.Cells(2, wsSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For i = 2 To lastColumn
        If wsSource.Cells(2, i) = "" Then
            'Do something here if cell is empty
        Else
            'Copy data to another worksheet
            wsSource.Cells(2, i).Copy
            wsDestination.Cells(2, i - 5).PasteSpecial 'You can use other Paste options
            'Also it copies from starting column H and pasts to starting from column C, by doing some math 'i-5'
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I have covered here your first portion, you can add more functionality to code above.

---

Or maybe even something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim lastRow As Long   
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet: Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NANF Formatted")
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet: Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NANF")
    
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Copy range
    wsSource.Range("H2:N2" & lastRow).Copy
    
    wsDestination.Range("C2").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```